# Find sum in one column for rows containing the same value in another column

Tags: excel, google-sheets, vlookup

I have a table like this:

```
Column I | Column J
====================
Peter          2
Martin         3
Peter          1
John           5
Peter          2
```

What I need is to sum the numbers for Peter, for example. So for Peter, I'd expect a result of 5.

I tried to achieve this by using a `VLOOKUP` function, but it seems to be working only for one row, so I have:

`=VLOOKUP("Peter";I4:J4;2)+VLOOKUP("Peter";I5:J5;2)+VLOOKUP("Peter";I6:J6;2)+VLOOKUP("Peter";I7:J7;2)`

However I have a lot of data like this, so it would be very long and would take me ages to write this down for all of them.

Any better solution, please?

**EDIT**: I'm working in Google Online Spreadsheets, so I don't know if a macro solution would be the best (or if it would even work).

Comment: Use a pivot table.

Comment: At minimum SUMIF()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=SUMIF(I:I,"Peter",J:J)
```